# Re-ordering images in existing post in wordpress 3.6.1

Tags: images, gallery

I hope someone can help me. I cannot see how to re-order images once loaded to the media gallery.

WordPress used to have a list view of all images in a post with a box you could enter the running order numerically or descending/ ascending etc...

Now I can only see all my images in the main media library and cannot see anyway or re-numbering or moving them.

Answer (score 2):

A screenshot explain better than words:

[image: post gallery ordering screenshot]

Comment: @SimonHarvey glat it works. I'm saying the following because you are new to this site: if the answer works for you, you should mark it as accepted. On top-left there is a number indicating the votes of the answer, under it there is a grey check sign. Click on it to accept answer. :)

Comment: +1, nice screenshot, yes it's much easier to use drag/drop than changing the shortcode by hand ;-)

Comment: Thanks @birgire. Yes, I think that core developers have that in mind while developing new media uploader.